# Using U2F from a custom Chrome extension instead of a regular web page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fido-u2f

I want to use custom Chrome extension as a frontend for my service, and I need authentication via U2F. Seems like a legitimate use case, but I have some doubts whether it's possible. E.g. the [rules for AppID](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/App_ID.html) say that `AppID` could only be `https://...`, `android:...` or `ios:...`, and no mention of `chrome-extension://`.

Just to make sure, I've written a small snippet which tries to trigger the u2f token registration from a chrome extension (where `gfljdbncaopiledjkfbcheahnbimjalm` is obviously an ID of it) :

```
window.u2f.register(
  "chrome-extension://gfljdbncaopiledjkfbcheahnbimjalm",
  [{
    version: "U2F_V2",
    challenge: "YXJlIHlvdSBib3JlZD8gOy0p",
  }],
  [],
  function(a) {
    console.log("cb called", a);
  }
);
```

But getting

`{errorCode: 2}`

(which means "bad request", including the malformed AppID).

Is it really not possible at all? If yes, is there any good reason for that?

Comment: Extensions are easy to overlook. Many developers may not know such technology exists. Sometimes even in Chrome the newly added features don't work with extensions initially until someone adds the support later on.

Comment: hey, did you find how to do this?